# Late 90's or early 00's fantasy comic

Tags: story-identification, comics

I recall reading a comic in the early 2000's that I am unable to recall the name of.  I do remember bits of the story however:

The main character was a girl with magical powers and an evil uncle who had staged her parents death and wanted to control her.  She was working on increasing her powers to defeat him.

There was an airship, and many battles features the heroes killing goblins.

Sorry I don't really recall more.  Does anyone know what this may have been?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**That's [Meridian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(comics)) a series published by the now defunct [CrossGen Comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossGen).**

[image]

Here's the blurb from the first volume of the series:

> Meridian is the story of Sephie, a sheltered young girl whose life
>   resembles nothing so much as a fairy tale. The beloved only child of
>   the Minister of Meridian, she grows up with an entire floating city as
>   her playground. Then her father dies, and she inherits a sigil imbued
>   with the power to create. So does her wicked Uncle Ilahn, except that
>   his powers are bent on destruction and domination. Suddenly Sephie
>   finds herself at the center of a power struggle, and quickly she
>   learns that there is more than love in the world. Kidnapped to the
>   world of Calador, Sephie's journey home to Meridian puts her in the
>   path of many people good and bad that help her grow up and counter
>   Ilahn's plans to take over her world.

**The series ran for 44 issues (July 2000 - April 2004) but only the first 26 issues were collected:**

- Meridian Volume 1: Flying Solo [1 - 7]
- Meridian Volume 2: Going to Ground [8 - 14]
- Meridian Volume 3: Taking the Skies [15 - 20]
- Meridian Volume 4: Coming Home [21 - 26]

The compendia collection series [FORGE](https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=698631) actually re-prints the series up until issues 30 or so.

Comment: Thanks 22nd Century Fza, this is it.  Been driving me crazy trying to think of the name!

Comment: Sure thing... I really enjoyed this series, it's a shame no one picked it up from CrossGen when they went bankrupt.